mvn -v JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly but it's already correct
I've looked at other problems. This one is new.
Installation
sudo apt install openjdk-21-jdk
sudo apt install maven
# open new shell

Environment check
(base) nghia@nghia-home ➜  ~ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/opt/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64
(base) nghia@nghia-home ➜  ~ realpath $(which java)
/opt/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
(base) nghia@nghia-home ➜  ~ java --version
openjdk 21.0.5 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.5+11-Ubuntu-1ubuntu124.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.5+11-Ubuntu-1ubuntu124.04, mixed mode, sharing)
(base) nghia@nghia-home ➜  ~ realpath $(which mvn)
/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn

Still failure
(base) nghia@nghia-home ➜  ~ mvn -v
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

Java works just fine. Maven always fails.
I've tried apt install. I've tried manual install by downloaded and unzipping .tar for both jdk and mvn. Nothing works.

Does $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version work?

Hint: the "mvn" command is actually shell script, and it includes the code that checks that JAVA_HOME is set correctly + outputs that error.  You should be able to debug the script to figure out what is going wrong ... on your machine.

Try to verify the maven settings.xml in ~/.m2/ directory - if anything like <env.JAVA_HOME>. Or else you can also try mvn -Djava.home=/opt/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64

Interesting . Did it  set $JAVA_HOME for you in some way?

Make sure you haven't got a config file for Maven under your home directory

There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live

[Self-answer]
Turns out there was a ~/.mavenrc that points to a non-existing (deleted) $JAVA_HOME.
I wish there was an easier way to debug this kind of thing. Specifically: debug where an environment variable was set.

You're welcome ;)
